# Is there a way I can clone my current Ubuntu setup?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

Currenly I have an Ubuntu environment on my laptop and I want to use this same environment in my desktop computer that has Windows installed and I would like to use the same Ubuntu from my laptop on my desktop computer with dual boot without losing any files or configs and stuff.

Is there a way I can create a custom image of my current Ubuntu so I can install it on my Windows Desktop with dual boot and without losing any files/softwares?

Nothing is encrypted on my laptop.

Comment: The general answer is "Yes, you can clone your current Ubuntu setup, for example with [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org)". But if you use that cloned image, you will probably overwrite your current Windows in the desktop computer. I would recommend that you **install** Ubuntu alongside Windows (which is quick and easy), and install your extra programs and do the tweaks (which may take some time).

Comment: The Clonezilla approach could work without too much trouble if you have a spare disk for it that you can add to your desktop. If not and you don't mind a lot of fiddling you could use the principles of Arch Linux installation guide but without using the arch tools. i.e. create your partitions, copy every file from your laptop Ubuntu environment, chroot into your copied system from a live disk, install grub.... This might work but installing from scratch is probably easier as suggested by sudodus. You will also have to pay attention to which mode you are using on both machines UEFI or Legacy.